MongoDB - OpLog connecting to different shard than where collection is present while watching change stream
I have a 3 shard mongo cluster running 5.0v
Each shard is a 3 node replicaSet
It's fronted by a 3 node config server replicaset and finally by a mongos server
Pretty standard
The application is connecting to the mongos server using pymongo 3.7 (tested on 3.13 as well)
Issue:
**Collection A of Db B is present on SHARD3 . The collection isn't sharded **. # This is Important to remember.
CRUD operations are working fine on this collection.
But, as soon as I start watching for changes on collection A,
with collectionA.watch(start_at_operation_time=Timestamp(some_date_present_in_oplog,1)) as stream:
    for change in stream:
        print(change)

Exception:
'Error on remote shard SHARD2:port
Executor error during getMore :: caused by :: Resume of change stream was not possible, as the resume point may no longer be in the oplog.
First it wasn't clear what's going on so I check the oplog entries on each of the SHARDS(1,2,3)
SHARD3 is where my collection is present has oplog entries way before my supplied timestamp, then after checking the error, realised it is trying to read oplog from SHARD2 instead of SHARD3 where indeed the oplog is quite recent.
On SHARD2
rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   30374.423828125MB
log length start to end: 99129secs (27.54hrs)
oplog first event time:  Tue Jun 25 2024 10:48:49 GMT+0530 (IST)
oplog last event time:   Wed Jun 26 2024 14:20:58 GMT+0530 (IST)
now:                     Wed Jun 26 2024 14:20:58 GMT+0530 (IST)

On SHARD3
rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   30374.4169921875MB
log length start to end: 8905804secs (2473.83hrs)
oplog first event time:  Fri Mar 15 2024 12:31:39 GMT+0530 (IST)
oplog last event time:   Wed Jun 26 2024 14:21:43 GMT+0530 (IST)
now:                     Wed Jun 26 2024 14:21:47 GMT+0530 (IST)

Help Required:
I am right now not able figure out what's causing it to query SHARD2 while watching changes. Need help figure this out
Trying going through the documentation and change logs to see if this issue was addressed but couldn't find anything

Which shard does sh.status() say that collectionA resides?

That is on SHARD3. I even checked the same on the config server(it was already correct) and then still refreshed the mongos server cache. The mapping on db to shard is correct here. Which makes sense as all other queries are working fine.

A trick that worked for me here was that I directly connected to SHARD3 Primary bypassing the mongos server to be able to read the Oplog only from SHARD3. But this isn't a solution, it's just a workaround. Ideally this should be what the router should have done


Help Required: I am right now not able figure out what's causing it to query SHARD2 while watching changes. Need help figure this out
Trying going through the documentation and change logs to see if this issue was addressed but couldn't find anything

I think the Sharded Cluster Considerations section of the documentation contains the answer and relevant information (emphasis theirs):

When a change stream is opened on a sharded cluster:

The mongos creates individual change streams on each shard. This behavior occurs regardless of whether the change stream targets a particular shard key range.


If I were to speculate, this behavior is probably to ensure logical correctness of the results. In your situation, for example, we could imagine that your Change Stream would return incomplete results if part of your collection were to be moved (balanced) to SHARD2 at some point in time after the timestamp of the resume token that you have specified and the system was not also monitoring SHARD2 for those changes/results.
We can see hints at this requirement in the Change Streams Production Recommendations for Sharded clusters:

Change streams provide a total ordering of changes across shards by utilizing a global logical clock. MongoDB guarantees the order of changes are preserved and change stream notifications can be safely interpreted in the order received.
...
To guarantee total ordering of changes, for each change notification the mongos checks with each shard to see if the shard has seen more recent changes.

The most correct way to solve the problem is to increase the available oplog on the other two shards and/or reduce the timestamp of the resume token. As you mentioned in your comment, the workaround to connect directly to the shard is not a proper solution and violates the change stream instruction that:


For a sharded cluster, you must issue the open change stream operation from the mongos.



Ideally this should be what the router should have done

It's not obvious that this can be safely done in general. While the results are correct in your specific example, the thought exercise above suggests that it only holds under certain constraints and would not always be true.
Perhaps there is some potential optimization here in this specific that could be done which would effectively check to make sure that there were no topological changes to the collection that happened between the resume token and start of the oplog on the other shards. If so that sounds like a feature request to the vendor but also a potentially niche scenario. It is probably not a common situation for all of the following to be true:

The duration of the oplogs between shards to be substantially different, on the order of 100x in this case
Resume tokens to be specified that are covered by the oplog on one shard but not all of them
The collection of interest to only fall on the shard(s) with oplog coverage.


Thanks. I did not consider the rebalancing scenario. It is making sense now.
True, it worked for my use case as that particular DB always resided in that particular shard but that isn't obvious to be used as a general case.
It will be really helpful if you can point me to the files(or some entry-point) inside mongo github repo where I can get a better understanding of this behaviour.
And thanks a lot, this was really helpful
